# How to pass the name of one controller to another controller ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass the name of Home controller to Article controller based on which I'm trying to assign a _layout page.

Following is my code which i have tried.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["Ctrl"] = "Home";
    }
}

public class ArticleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (TempData["Ctrl"] != null)
        {
            return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml", articles);
        }
        return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_otherLayout.cshtml", articles);
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm assigning `TempData` value in each and every method in the Home controller (which I don't want to do it) as I'm losing `TempData` value. I tried assigning the value in the constructor of home controller without luck.

Could anyone please help me or point me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: what's your scenario? I can't get when you call method. Don't you want just save this value to Session?

Comment: `Session["Ctrl"]` may work across page requests, I prefer the session state mechanism rather than using `TempData` which lost its value on certain point of request-response sequence.

Comment: you can use session variable for holding value and you need to set only once for one session

Comment: have you had a look into the DependencyResolver.Current ?

Comment: Your application will use `_otherLayout.cshtml` unless you first navigate to `Home/Index` (or `/`). What is the point? Why would you want the application to do that? It seems like it would be easier and more reliable to add a query string or route parameter to control the layout instead trying to use session, which requires you to navigate in a specific sequence in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. @NightOwl888, in my Home Page there are some articles, when the user clicks on one of the article from Home  Page (Home Controller) the user is redirected to Articles Controller Details Method this is where i am checking where the request is coming from i.e., Home or some other controller so that i can assign layout page, hope that explains

Comment: @user3543878 - Okay, but what happens if the user navigates to the article page *directly* from a search results page or from a link on Facebook? There is no way to force the user to always visit your home page before visiting the article (in fact it may be a minority of the traffic). Site navigation shouldn't depend on session, because for that to work you are concluding that the only path to the page is through another page, which usually isn't true. Instead, you should put this state in the URL so it is there regardless of where the user comes from.

Comment: @NightOwl888 you mean something like his in the view @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", "Articles", new { id = item.ArticleId, ctrl = "Home" }, null ) ?

Comment: @user3543878 - that is one way. You might want to add a route to the application so the URL is generated like `{ctrl}\Article\{id}` (or something along those lines), but it would be better for SEO if you include the Title of the article in the URL. Alternatively, you could tie the layout to the article itself so when you look the article up from the data store (based on the article ID from the URL) it also includes the layout to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your data in the `Session` object

`this.HttpContext.Session.Add("Ctrl","Home")`